# declaring multiple columns in a count value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to define multiple count values for a counter and corresponding value. Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @RequestDate AS DATE = '2017-04-20'
;
DECLARE @POCounter INT;
DECLARE @POMax INT;
DECLARE @NewDate DATE;

SET @POCounter = 0;

SET @POMax = 
(
SELECT
    CUSTOMERPONUMBER,
    (
    SELECT 
    COUNT(CUSTOMERPONUMBER) 
    FROM DailyOpenOrders$ 
    WHERE
    RequestDate < @RequestDate
    ) 
FROM DailyOpenOrders$
WHERE
    RequestDate < @RequestDate
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMERPONUMBER
)
```

The @POMax counter is to help me update the date that many times for a specific customerPO. I intend to increase the POCounter in a loop until it reaches the @POmax counter for each customerPOnumber.

Am i doing this wrong? can someone help?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Sorry! MS SQL Server

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to do here. Your query will return multiple rows (and two columns). If you can explain what you are trying to accomplish we can help.

Comment: @SeanLange i am getting this error with the above code "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS".

Comment: Well yeah...that is part of my previous comment. But also have a scalar variable being set to a result set with multiple rows. The challenge is that you have only posted a snippet of code and no explanation of your goal.

Comment: Goal7: Yes, but what are you trying to do? Can you explain that better? maybe by showing sample data and expected results?

Comment: You mention looping in your post....you should avoid looping if at ALL possible. My guess is that in the end this can be a set based approach. But until we know the problem it is just a guess.

Comment: @SeanLange i am getting this error with the above code "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS".                                                                                                      I am trying to get all the CustomerPO's that are less than the "@requestdate". Count how many times each PO is within this data and add +1 to the request date that many times(count of PO times). Does this explain the problem better?

Comment: What do you mean by add +1 to the request date? You need to provide some details about what you want to accomplish. The best way is with some data and table structure. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: As for the error look at your code and think about what it is doing. You have a scalar variable and you are trying to assign its value to the query. But your query has two columns....which column should it use? The sql engine is not going to pick one for you because you have a logical error so you get the error message.

Comment: So for each `CUSTOMERPONUMBER` you want their number of records before `@RequestDate`? And then you want to do what exactly with those counts?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you are right. Once i have the count of records for each CUSTOMERPONUMBER that are before "@RequestDate", i want to have update each record of this date buy a new record until the count is zero. this means if CUSTOMERPONUMBER is repeated 5 times with different dates(count =5), i want update(requestdate +1) the date 5 times for that PO number

Answer (score 2):

@POMax is a scalar variable and can only hold one value at a time.

If you want to hold a collection of values, a table variable is a good tool for that:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
  ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  CustomerNumber varchar(50),
  [TheCount] int
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable(CustomerNumber, [TheCount])
SELECT CustomerNumber, COUNT(*)
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY CustomerNumber
```

Now you can loop over @MyTable, and for each CustomerNumber, loop from 1 to TheCount...

```
DECLARE @MyID int

SET @MyID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM @MyTable)

WHILE @MyID is not null
BEGIN

  SELECT * FROM @MyTable WHERE ID = @MyID

  SET @MyID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM @MyTable WHERE @MyID < ID)
END
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked like a charm. Can you help me looping "@Mytable" with a counter? I have never looped a table before.